# What are T4C8Oall and T4CTTIfun?

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

In ojdbc6, T4C8Oall commonly does get the bytes from the Oracle server. T4C8Oall  extends T4CTTIfun.
1) Why are are T4C8Oall and T4CTTIfun named as they are?
2) How does T4C8Oall get the bytes from the Oracle server?
3) Does T4C8Oall behave the same for all versions of Oracle servers?

Comment: As those are non public classes you should ask Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

1) These names are defined in the TTC protocol which isn't a publicly documented protocol. TTC (Two Task Common) is the protocol used by the Oracle Database server and is implemented by OCI (in C) and in the Oracle JDBC thin driver (in Java).

2) T4C8Oall gets the bytes from the Oracle server through this protocol. The rows are shipped one after the other in a single roundtrip.

3) T4C8Oall doesn't behave the same way for all versions of the Oracle servers. Newer versions will have additional data. The protocol is versioned and the version is negotiated during connection establishment.